# Excel Creating A Cell with multiple functionality

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. On the first and second sheets I have a drop down selector using 'Data Validation', the data is on hidden sheets that are created from an external data source. I am using INDEX and MATCH to display the data.

For Example

`|data_field_1|=INDEX(workSheet,MATCH(prevCell,workSheet[field],0),MATCH(workSheet[#Headers],0))|=prevCell|`

where | is the cell boundary. So the field name in the first cell is used to retrieve the data I wish to display in the second cell and the data is then displayed in the 3rd cell. 
So what I am trying to do is drive the second worksheet from the first, but also have the functionality in the same cell to also retrieve a different set of data if I require.

Scenario
If I have on the first page a drop down that has the values, 'AC/DC', 'Black Sabbath', 'Rush'. When I select 'AC/DC', on the second page what should then be displayed in the Drop Down is the Value 'High Voltage'. However I can also use this drop down to select other values, 'Dirty Deed', 'Let There Be Rock'. If I then go back to the first Page and instead pick 'Rush', I would expect the display on the second page to display 'Rush' with the drop down values that can be selected 'Fly By Night', 'Caress of Steel', '2112', ...

What is happening at the moment is I can get the first bit to work. When I pick AC/DC, on the second page I get 'High Voltage', however when I select from the second page 'Dirty Deeds' and then go back to page one and select 'Rush', I still have 'Dirty Deeds' on the second page instead of 'Rush'.

Is this possible to do? I have no experience with VBA, though if this is the way to fix my problem I would love to know the solution.

Many Thanks

Comment: Could you post some sample data in table format.

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in creating a cascading drop down list.  See https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/